# Solution Package - Deployment

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

What will happen if we installed a "Web-scoped" feature globally?

Answer (score 2):

There will not be any issue in deploying the feature globally. The only problem(?) is that it will be avalable in all webapplications in your farm.

Comment: Lets say that we have developed a solution package for a specific web-application however deployed globally, does it make any difference?

Comment: if you want this feature only in a specific web application, the best approach is to deploy in that web application, so that it won't be available in other webapplication's sitecollection/site settings. You can globally deploy it, if you need this feature in all web application in a farm. (a farm/ server can contain many web application)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be any problems.
Simple answer:
The feature could potentially be turned on/off for certain sites/sub sites.